# How to see man page of a function of a user installed R library/package?

Tags: r

I have installed a library that contains lot of functions. I want to see calculations done in those functions. How to reach man page of these function in R prompt ?

I only know library(help="name of library") command to seek help.

Comment: Do you also know `?fnName` It works after the package is loaded but you can also use this form: `?pkgname::fnName` it that package exports the name, as is most often the case.

Comment: Thanks DWin, my query solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using the `ggplot2` package, go to google, type in something like :

```
'r ggplot2'
```

In the results look for the sites that look like this:

```
cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2
```

and start with `'cran.r-project.org/....'`

Click on that link and you will see a page for the package.  You want to click on either the `Reference Manual` or for some packages there are `Vignettes` with more involved explanations and examples.  However, the Reference Manual is usually pretty good for examples of how to use the package functions.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut is:

```
?command
```

The longer version, for commands such as `if` for which the shortcut won't work, is:

```
help("command")
```

If you need to find a command in installed packages:

```
help.search("command")
```

If you need to find a command in all possible packages, the `sos` library is the ticket.